# Background-right Height? (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I don't know why the length of my background-right length for my unordered list is longer than it should be. I'm still new to website development so if you see that I'm doing something wrong, let me know. This is what it looks like: http://gyazo.com/a2875f082f6a1424cf8be6d9ecdf100d
HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="indexCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <title>First webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navBarBlack"></div>
    <ul id="navBar">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 8</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p id="header">Webpage</p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    #header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #818181;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

body {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

#navBar li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 40px;
    border-right: thin solid white;
}
#navBar li:first-child{
    border-left: thin solid white;
}
#navBarBlack{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #212121;
    height: 30px;
    float: none;
    margin-top: -7px;
    width: 2000px;
    align-self: center;
    margin-left: -70px;
}
#navBar{
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    margin-top: -27px;
}
#navBar li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navBar li a:visited {
    color: #8A8A8A;
}

#navBar li a:link {
    color: #8A8A8A;
}

#navBar li a {
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
}

#navBar li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have your CSS to put a bunch of padding for each `<li>`. 40px to be exact. 
That means you're putting 40px on the top, right, bottom, and left of for each `<li>`. So it's adding 80px to the height. And it is causing the border to extend that full height.

So as a fix, you could change <del>`padding:40px;`</del> to `padding: 8px 40px;`. That is CSS short hand to set `padding-top` & `padding-bottom` to 8px each. And then `padding-right` & `padding-left` to 40px each.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to go for here, but I wouldn't recommend using so much padding. I'd recommend at least changing from `px` to `%`, that way when on a different screen size or a smaller browser window - it won't break your layout completely.

Answer (score 0):

Your   `<div id="navBarBlack"></div>` is closing before the `<ul>`

Move the closing `</div>` after the `<ul></ul>` so it encapsulates the navigation.

Comment: You can expand your answer by adding an example of the part that fixed  OPs code.

Answer (score 0):

The height of your `li` tags is 80px plus 1em. The border extends that whole length. Try setting the padding of your `li` tags to `padding: 4px 40px;` instead and see what happens. Play around with those values a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with your code and here are some pointers:

1. add background color on the ul or the li of the menu
2. use display inline-block or float left on the menu items and calculate what the width of each item would be in percentages.
3. look into box-sizing: border-box. This will save you alot of headache
4. dont use Ids to style your element. IDs are javascript. Always use classes

.
Finally the code I was playing with to show you what I changed:

http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/CFdGK